# PowerShell: Hash of arrays of hashes - looking for an advice

Tags: arrays, powershell, hash

to want have a fast access to complicated data and I'd like to organise them in a hash of arrays of hashes.
I am bit unsure as hashes look similar to arrays: How do I define that in a safe way?

Remark: I was first thinking if a simple hash of hashes but all the features of the shoes are not individual and could cause a key-collision, so I started thinking of an array of the most relevant feature.

1) The 'outer' keys are the [string]item-names (shoe-names),
2) then I want to have an array of [single] numbers (like size of shoes) and
3) 'behind' each number in the array I need a hash with further details of this shoe: @{"Color"="White"; "Material"="Leather";...}

This way I can easily scroll through:

```
 $item = @{
     "Shoe1 = @() # an array of sizes of that shoe-name
     "Shoe2 = @() # an array of sizes of that shoe-name
 }
```

so $item.Shoe1 should be an array of its sizes:

```
 foreach($size in $item.Shoe1) {
       if ( $size -gt 10.5 -or $size -lt 10.0 ) { continue }
       # how do I access the hash behind the size = an indiv. shoe?
       if($size.Color -eq 'white') {...}
 }
```

a) Would you suggest an other way?
b) How do I define this structure?
c) How can I add a size with its hash 'behind' to a shoe?

Thanks in advance!
Gooly

Comment: ok, could be misunderstood, I have changed my code.

Comment: Powershell v4 syntax: `$shoeDictionary.Loafer.Where( { $_.Size -eq 6 -and $_.Color -eq "White" } )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Entire answer revised based on 6/20 comment)*

Based on your feedback @gooly and a re-reading of your question, I am scrubbing my entire answer to give you something that should be more useful to you.
You are correct that a hash of arrays of hashes will work, as in this first example. Note that size 6 loafers come in 3 different color/material combinations:

```
$shoeDictionary = @{
     Loafer = @(
        @{ Size = 6; Color = "White"; Material = "Leather" },
        @{ Size = 6; Color = "Brown"; Material = "Faux Leather" },
        @{ Size = 6; Color = "Blue"; Material = "Leather" },
        @{ Size = 10.5; Color = "Black"; Material = "Patent Leather" }
     )
     Oxford = @(
        @{ Size = 5; Color = "Blue"; Material = "Leather" },
        @{ Size = 5.5; Color = "Green"; Material = "Faux Leather" }
     )
}
```

When you ask for a size 6 in white, you do not need any loops at all:

```
PS> $shoeDictionary.Loafer | Where { $_.Size -eq 6 -and $_.Color -eq "White" }

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Color                          White
Material                       Leather
Size                           6
```

But consider a broader question: show me all loafers in size 6, you get this:

```
PS> $shoeDictionary.Loafer | Where  Size -eq 6

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Color                          White
Material                       Leather
Size                           6
Color                          Brown
Material                       Faux Leather
Size                           6
Color                          Blue
Material                       Leather
Size                           6
```

... which is not terribly legible. A better choice is to think in terms of objects rather than hashes, that is a hash of arrays of **objects** rather than hash of arrays of **hashes**, to wit:

```
$shoeDictionary = @{
     Loafer = @(
        (New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Size = 6; Color = "White"; Material = "Leather" }),
        (New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Size = 6; Color = "Brown"; Material = "Faux Leather" }),
        (New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Size = 6; Color = "Blue"; Material = "Leather" }),
        (New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Size = 10.5; Color = "Black"; Material = "Patent Leather" })
     )
     Oxford = @(
        (New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Size = 5; Color = "Blue"; Material = "Leather" }),
        (New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Size = 5.5; Color = "Green"; Material = "Faux Leather" })
     )
}
```

Now when you look at all size 6 loafers you get this much more palatable result:

```
PS> $shoeDictionary.Loafer | Where Size -eq 6
Color Material     Size
----- --------     ----
White Leather         6
Brown Faux Leather    6
Blue  Leather         6
```

Comment: Well, of course I would prefer a 'simple' hash of hashes of hashes too! But as soon as you have two or more shoes with the same size this structure becomes even more difficult as you must do add. admin. work to make sure that all the shoes stay in that hash and are not 'overwritten' by the next one. A list of different keys is perfect for a hash but a list of probably same values would be easier organized in an array - no?

Comment: @gooly: See my completely revised answer above.